# Need a more efficient threshold matching with function for R

Tags: r, function, apply

Not sure how best to ask this question, so feel free to edit the question title if there is a more standard vocabulary to use here.

I have two 2-column data tables in R, the first is a list of unique 2-variable values (u), so much shorter than the second, which is a raw list of similar values (d). I need a function that will, for every 2-variable set of values in u, find all the 2-variable sets of values in d for which both variables are within a given threshold.

Here's a minimal example. Actual data is much larger (see below, as this is the problem) and (obviously) not created randomly as in the example. In the actual data, u would have about 600,000 to 1,000,000 values (rows) and d would have upwards of 10,000,000 rows.

```
# First create the table of unique variable pairs (no 2-column duplicates)
u <- data.frame(PC1=c(-1.10,-1.01,-1.13,-1.18,-1.12,-0.82),
                PC2=c(-1.63,-1.63,-1.81,-1.86,-1.86,-1.77))

# Now, create the set of raw 2-variable pairs, which may include duplicates
d <- data.frame(PC1=sample(u$PC1,100,replace=T)*sample(90:100,100,replace=T)/100,
                PC2=sample(u$PC2,100,replace=T)*sample(90:100,100,replace=T)/100)

# Set the threshold that defined a 'close-enough' match between u and d values
b <- 0.1
```

So, my first attempt to do this was with a for loop for all values of u. This works nicely, but is computationally intensive and takes quite a while to process the actual data.

```
# Make a list to output the list of within-threshold  rows
m <- list()
# Loop to find all values of d within a threshold b of each value of u
# The output list will have as many items as values of u
# For each list item, there may be up to several thousand matching rows in d
# Note that there's a timing command (system.time) in here to keep track of performance
system.time({
  for(i in 1:nrow(u)){
      m <- c(m, list(which(abs(d$PC1-u$PC1[i])<b & abs(d$PC2-u$PC2[i])<b)))
  } 
})
m
```

That works. But I thought using a function with apply() would be more efficient. Which it is...

```
# Make the user-defined function for the threshold matching
match <- function(x,...){
  which(abs(d$PC1-x[1])<b & abs(d$PC2-x[2])<b)
}
# Run the function with the apply() command.
system.time({
  m <- apply(u,1,match)
})
```

Again, this apply function works and is slightly faster than the for loop, but only marginally. This may simply be a big data problem for which I need a bit more computing power (or more time!). But I thought others might have thoughts on a sneaky command or function syntax that would dramatically speed this up. Outside the box approaches to finding these matching rows also welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat sneaky:

```
library(IRanges)
ur <- with(u*100L, IRanges(PC2, PC1))
dr <- with(d*100L, IRanges(PC2, PC1))
hits <- findOverlaps(ur, dr + b*100L)
```

Should be fast once the number of rows is sufficiently large. We multiply by 100 to get into integer space. Reversing the order of the arguments to `findOverlaps` could improve performance.

Comment: How large do the number of rows need to get? So far this is quite slow compared to other methods according to `microbenchmark`

Comment: You're right, it does not perform very favorably, since at least in this example, there are many hits, and the hits are manipulated,  including being sorted for convenience; the function is optimized for sparser data.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, this seems only slightly faster than the `for` loop

```
unlist(Map(function(x,y) {
    which(abs(d$PC1-x)<b & abs(d$PC2-y)<b)
}, u$PC1, u$PC2))
```

but at least it's something.

Answer (score 1):

I have a cunning plan :-) .  How about just doing calculations:

```
> set.seed(10)
> bar<-matrix(runif(10),nc=2)
> bar
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.50747820 0.2254366
[2,] 0.30676851 0.2745305
[3,] 0.42690767 0.2723051
[4,] 0.69310208 0.6158293
[5,] 0.08513597 0.4296715
> foo<-c(.3,.7)
> thresh<-foo-bar
> sign(thresh)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]   -1    1
[4,]    1   -1
[5,]    1    1
```

Now all you have to do is select the rows of that last matrix which are  `c(-1,1)`  , using `which` , and you can easily extract the desired rows from your `bar` matrix.  Repeat for each row in `foo`.

Comment: Thanks Carl, this definitely works. But to loop it for each row takes longer than the which() based function.